# Conditions for the implicit function theorem being satisfied giving rise to $n-1$ dimensional manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, mathematical-physics, jacobian, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to understand an example from Thirring's Classical Mathematical Physics, 2nd ed., p. 14.

[image]

I want to understand how the condition on $M$ satisfies the condition for the implicit function theorem.

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^{(n-m)+m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$. Then, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Definitions), what is necessary is that $Y$ be invertible, where $(df)(\mathbf{a, b}) = [X | Y]$. But if I understand correctly, the condition on $M$ only guarantees that for every row in $Y$, there exists a non-zero entry. It may be the case that $Y$ be singular.

Is it necessary that $m<n$ for $f$ to make sense? Assuming that the conditions for the implicit function theorem are satisfied, how did we get an $n-1$ dimensional manifold? Shouldn't we get an $n-m$ dimensional manifold?

Comment: Thirring is considering the case of $m=1$. But his use of $f_{i,j}$ is then kind of silly. He should just say $f_{j}(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}(x)\neq 0$. Also, you don’t need $n>m$, but simply $n\geq m$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok, perhaps that is what he meant. I shall assume that is that case because it makes sense then. Thanks